# Navigate when clicking on image doesn't work

Tags: react-native, routes, navigation, frontend, react-navigation

I've been trying to be able to change screens by clicking on the Image within the code but it isn't working.

I've tried defining Push, navigate and other props but it always says that undefined is not an object and show the prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Button } from "react-native";
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import { StackNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Screen from './Screen'

export default class Additional extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
          navigate("Screen")}
        >
          <Image
            style={{
              tintColor: "#9B9B9B", height: 56, width: 56,
              position: 'absolute', alignSelf: 'center', top: wp('-84.0%'), left: wp('5%'),
            }}
            source={require("../Icons/XButton.png")}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Screen: {screen: Screen},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tested to make sure `navigate` is not `undefined`?  It's not clear from your code how `Additional` relates to the stack navigator.

Comment: @MikeM Well, the Additional file is an image where when clicked takes me to Screen. I have run the app and if I click on the icon many times it gives me the error mentioned "undefined is not an object ". If there are any other tests I can run please do tell

Comment: If `Additional` is just the image (and not a screen), then it doesn't have access to the navigation props unless you pass them explicitly.

Comment: So you would need to call it like `<Additional navigation=this.props.navigation />` from the parent screen.

Comment: @MikeM I've added it to the parent it said that navigate isn't a variable so I wrote     const  {navigate}  = this.props.navigation and it gave me another error with undefined object. So I've decided to add "this.props.navigation" to the parent of the parent and the screen works but when I click on the icon it just shows opacity and doesn't navigate to the screen, staying on the same page

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm not sure what's going on, but only screens listed in the `createStackNavigator`  will have direct access to the `this.props.navigation` object.

Comment: @MikeM I posted it below, Yeah I know for createStackNavigator , Screen is a simple styleSheet  in case you need to know

Comment: You need to pass the navigation props to `Sidebar`.

Comment: @MikeM sorry my bad I actually tried that already as mentioned on my 3rd comment. I was just testing it around. Here I edited it back, it's still the same result it stays on the maps page

Comment: it looks like you created the `AppNavigator` object but never used it anywhere.

Comment: @MikeM In Sidebar? I removed it, but the result persists, maybe there is another way to structure this, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Parent:

i

```
mport React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native" ;
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import Additional from './Additional'
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import Screen from './Screen'

export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(

        <View style={styles.container}>



        <Additional navigation={this.props.navigation} />


                 </View>
        ) 
    }
}


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: Map,
  },
  Screen: {
    screen: Screen,
  },
}, {

});


const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    container:{ 
         flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.81)',
       left: wp('75%'),
        width: 100,


}})
```

Grandparent:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import MenuButton from './MenuButton'
import SideBar from './SideBar'





const {width, height} = Dimensions.get ('window')

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = height / width
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO
export default class App extends Component {

constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state ={
  initialPosition: {
latitude: 0,
longitude: 0,
latitudeDelta: 0,
longitudeDelta: 0

  },
  markerPosition: {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
  }
}
  }

watchID: ?number = null

componentDidMount(){

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ((position) =>{
var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

var initialRegion = {

latitude : lat,
longitude: long,
latitudeDelta : LATITUDE_DELTA,
longitudeDelta : LONGITUDE_DELTA

}
this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
this.setState({markerPosition: initialRegion})
  },
 (error) => alert (JSON.stringify(error)),
 {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000})

 this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

var lastRegion = {
  latitude: lat,
longitude: long,
latitudeDelta : LATITUDE_DELTA,
longitudeDelta : LONGITUDE_DELTA
}
this.setState({initialPosition: lastRegion})
this.setState({markerPosition: lastRegion})

}

 )}


componentWillUnmount(){
   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
 }



render() {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>

      <MapView
       customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        style={styles.map}
        region={this.state.initialPosition}>


      <MapView.Marker
     coordinate= {this.state.markerPosition}>
     <View style = {styles.radius}>
       <View style = {styles.marker}>

       </View>
        </View>
     </MapView.Marker>
      </ MapView>
      <SideBar navigation= {this.props.navigation}/>
      <View style={styles.Mstyle}>
<MenuButton navigation= {this.props.navigation}/>
      </View>


</View>
    )

  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 radius: {
height: 50,
width: 50,
borderRadius: 50/2,
overflow: 'hidden',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.1)',
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: 'rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.3)',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
  },
marker: {

 height: 20,
 width: 20,
 borderWidth: 3,
 borderColor: 'white',
 borderRadius: 20 / 2,
overflow: 'hidden',
backgroundColor: '#007AFF'
},


 Mstyle: {
      alignSelf:'center',
      position: 'absolute'
},

 container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',

  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'

 },
 map: {
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  position: 'absolute'
 },

});


 AppRegistry.registerComponent('mapsTutorial', ()=> mapsTutorial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Additional` is not in `createStackNavigator` screens list. So, `this.props.navigation` is `undefined`. 
To cover this, first, you have to `export default AppNavigator` , and in another component (for example `Additional`) you must use `withNavigation` method.

In root component:

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Screen: {screen: Screen},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

In Additional component:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

class Additional extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

export default withNavigation(Additional)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried exporting createStackNavigator as mentioned on top in root and other components to try out but it's not working. Is there another way to approach it, or would it be best we have a live chat so that I can show you the code and we can work on it? Thanks

Comment: yeah, do you have skype or slack?

Comment: Yes. give me your skype id please.