# Trying to navigate to another screen based on text click, but got an error "undefined is not an object (evaluation navigate.navigateToScreen)"

Tags: react-native, navigation, frontend, undefined

I've been trying to navigate from Text to another screen but this error pops up, can anyone please help

This is a testing sheet for a bigger problem I have posted here [Navigate when clicking on image doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007062/navigate-when-clicking-on-image-doesnt-work/56036992#56036992) , I am trying to structure my code to navigate from an Image to a page. Thanks for helping

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import AddDocScreen from './Menu/AddDocScreen'

export default class Mock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const navigate = this.props.navigation

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigate.navigateToScreen(navigationAction)}>
          <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const navigationAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'AddDocSreen',
})

function navigateToScreen(navigationAction) {
  () => {
    return navigationAction
  }
}

const doc = createStackNavigator({
  AddDocScreen: { screen: AddDocScreen },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(215,215,215,1)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

Comment: You can use navigation only for the screens which are defined in stackNavigator. Your stackNavigator only has one screen, so the screen you are trying to navigate from should also be in stackNavigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import AddDocScreen from './Menu/AddDocScreen'

class Mock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',backgroundColor: 'rgba(215,215,215,1)'}}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>
          <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Mock: Mock,
    AddDocScreen: AddDocScreen,
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Mock',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Some typo errors but it's working. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the main problem still. thought you solved it so here.